# How to report filenames found by strings after being piped through grep?

Tags: grep, strings

I've been around *nix long enough to remember having done this in the past, and now those neural pathways are gone...  I'm searching /usr/local/lib for files that contain *img_convert* because I'm getting a link error and want to find the library to include which contains that reference.

This command finds the reference, but doesn't print the containing file names:

```
$ strings /usr/local/lib/* | grep 'img_convert'
img_convert
img_convert
```

Of course, I could script this, however I'm sure there's a way to do this from the command line... so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
strings --print-file-name /usr/local/lib/* | grep 'img_convert'
```

Note that this will work with GNU `strings`, but not necessarily with other versions.

Comment: THANKS!  On my particular flavor it was "--print-file-name".

Answer (score 3):

Grep is happy to read binary files and search for the string itself so

```
grep -l img_convert /usr/local/lib/*
```

should do what you want.

Comment: WAT? grep speaks binary?  thanks for the tip.